# Changing basis of indeterminates in polynomial ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, galois-theory, computational-mathematics, computer-algebra-systems, groebner-basis

In the polynomial ring $R={\mathbb Q}[a,b,c,d,\beta_0,\beta_1,\beta_2,\beta_3]$, consider 
the quotient commutative algebra $A=R/I$ where $I$ is the ideal generated by the four polynomials

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
P_0 &=& \frac{1}{(ac)^2B_1}\big(\beta_0 M-(a^2c^2B_1)^4\big) \\
P_1 &=& \frac{1}{c^2C_1D_1}\big(\beta_1 M-(c^2C_1D_1)^4\big) \\
P_2 &=& \frac{1}{a^2C_2D_1}\big(\beta_2 M-(a^2C_2D_1)^4\big) \\
P_3 &=&  \frac{1}{B_1C_1D_2} \big(\beta_3 M-(B_1C_1D_2)^4\big) \\
\end{array}
$$

where 
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
B_1 =\frac{ab+cd}{2}, & C_1 =\frac{ac+bd}{2}, & D_1 =\frac{ad+bc}{2}, \\
B_2 =\frac{ab-cd}{2}, & C_2 =\frac{ac-bd}{2}, & D_2 =\frac{ad-bc}{2}, \\  
\end{array}
$$

and

$$M=(abcd)^2B_1C_1D_1B_2C_2D_2.$$

If we consider the field of fractions $F$ of $A$, then $F$ is obviously isomorphic  to ${\mathbb Q}(a,b,c,d)$, since in $F$ each of the $\beta_k$ is a rational function in $a,b,c,d$. But things become very different when we consider $F$ as an extension of ${\mathbb Q}(\beta_0,\beta_1,\beta_2,\beta_3)$, i.e. when we try to express $a,b,c,d$ in terms of the $\beta_k$. Can we do it using radicals, i.e. by finding a tower of radical extensions between ${\mathbb Q}(\beta_0,\beta_1,\beta_2,\beta_3)$ and $F$ ? If not, can we at least describe the Galois group of $F/{\mathbb Q}(\beta_0,\beta_1,\beta_2,\beta_3)$ ?

**Motivation :** Up to a few natural simplifications, this change of variables is precisely the one that Borchardt used in his proof that the limit of a fourth-order generalized AGM sequence  can be written as an integral (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2117142/a-known-closed-form-for-borchardt-mean-generalization-of-agm-why-doesnt-it/2654571?noredirect=1#comment5482643_2654571))

**My thoughts :** I tried to implement the computations in PARI/GP but my computer got stuck doing multiplications of large polynomials.

Comment: When you say "$F$ is obviously isomorphic to $\mathbb Q(a,b,c,d)$", do you actually mean that $F = \mathbb{Q}(\bar a, \bar b, \bar c, \bar d)$ where $\bar a$ is the image of $a$ in $F$, and so on?

Comment: @Doris Yes. (chars added to fit the minimum here)